# Factor multiple routes that have similar patterns (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

How could I factor this code. i'm a Rails newbie and know it should be possible to DRY this and factor it:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do 

match "/france",          to: 'static_pages#set_france_in_session_and_redirect',          via: 'get'
match "/germany",         to: 'static_pages#set_germany_in_session_and_redirect',         via: 'get'
match "/unitedstates",    to: 'static_pages#set_us_in_session_and_redirect', path: 'us',  via: 'get'
match "/andsoon.....",    to: 'static_pages#set_us_in_session_and_redirect', path: 'us',  via: 'get'

end
```

As i will use it for about 20 countries couldn't I factor this , in order , not to have 20 lines of code?

**EDIT**

**#####################################**

Following all the insightful answers/suggestions (thanks!), I think I have not provided enough context and info on my objectives. So I'll give here more insights as answers do not answer what I'd like to do due to lack of relevant info on my part.

Here's the deal: I'm trying to build a daily deal Rails app.

I have a homepage called http://myapp.com

Thanks to IP detection (geocoder gem), when a French user loads the homepage, he arrives on http://myapp.com and I only display content for French people (deals for French residents).

Now, the user has the ability to go to a page called http://myapp.com/global and chooses another country if he wishes: see below

[image]

If he clicks on "Germany", this does basically 2 things:

1. set in session[:country]= Germany
2. then redirects him to the homepage myapp.com (but with 'germany' now stored in the session so I can only display to him 'deals for German residents')

I have **one BIG constraint** that I know is not very Rails-way but definitely want to keep it like that : **I want the URL visitors see in the browser to always be http://myapp.com and NOT http://myapp.com/france or http://myapp.com/germany, and so on...**

So that's why I could not use params as one person suggested
session[:counrty] = params[:country]

Indeed, using params[:country] would result in the creation of URLs like http://myapp.com/country=germany or http://myapp.com/germany (maybe I'm too newbie but I could not make it work, and use params while having  only ONE url of homepage that reads http://myapp.com)

So the "trick" I found which is not Rails-way and I know it's not object oriented is the following:

The page http://myapp.com/global

```
<p>
<%= link_to "MyApp France", france_path, 
            confirm: "Are you sure you want to switch to MyApp France?" %><br/>
<%= link_to "MyApp  Germany", germany_path,
            confirm: "Are you sure you want to switch to MyApp Germany? " %><br/>
<%=  link_to "MyApp  US", unitedstates_path,
            confirm: "Are you sure you want to switch to MyApp US? " %>  
</p>
```

Then once they clicked on this link (for example on the german one), the visitor is sent to 
germany_path for which I created a route:

```
  match "/france",          to: 'static_pages#set_france_in_session_and_redirect',          via: 'get'
  match "/germany",         to: 'static_pages#set_germany_in_session_and_redirect',         via: 'get'
  match "/unitedstates",    to: 'static_pages#set_us_in_session_and_redirect', path: 'us',  via: 'get'
```

And static_pages#set_germany_in_session_and_redirect points to /app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:

```
# Enable not logged-in user to choose country version in the page/global)
  def set_france_in_session_and_redirect
    session[:country] = "France"
    redirect_to_root
  end


  def set_germany_in_session_and_redirect
    session[:country] = "Germany"
    redirect_to_root
  end

  def set_us_in_session_and_redirect
    session[:country] = "United States"
    redirect_to_root
  end
```

Clearly it's not Rails-way and I want to improve that, learning from you guys but I don't know how to do it.

Can you help me do this but in a better Rails-way, clean and proper ?

Comment: You made 20 different controller actions for this and you are worried about 20 lines of code in routes.rb :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you made 20 different actions for setting one session variable only. So combine all action and make one action and send country info/name in parameters and there set in session and redirect it appropriately.

```
def set_countries_session
  session[:counrty] = params[:country]
  redirect 'your path'
end
```

If you still want to go with your approach of 20 actions and then you can refactor your routes code by using an array of countries

```
['germany', 'france', 'so on'].each do |country|
  match "/#{country}", to: "static_pages#set_#{country}_in_session_and_redirect",  via: 'get'
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! but I don't think I can use params. I understood I failed to give enough context/explanations so I edited my question => see EDIT

Comment: This **is** the rails way.  If you want to do it the Rails way, do this.  Yes, it breaks your desire to have all links be "myapp.com", but that constraint is itself not railsy.  It's inherently not RESTful and RESTfulness is built into Rails.

Comment: Oh, and as a note: if you do this, your links will look like "myapp.com/france" BUT, when a user clicks that link, they should briefly go to that url before being redirected to "myapp.com" again.  That may be enough for you for now.

Comment: @Mathieu Even making separate actions for each countries will clash with your constraint(not showing anything in url). The non rails of doing that is to make set_country_session action post. create separate form or field  and on clicking any link submit particular form. In post params go in http message body hence not visible on urls

Answer (score 2):

**Routes**

Rails' routing structure is built around [`resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default), which is built on the [object-orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) nature of Ruby (the language which Rails is built on)

Simply, your *routes* should reflect the *objects* you wish to populate, NOT the "functionality" you wish to achieve. It's a bit of a mind-bender to begin with, but once you realize how it works, it becomes a lot simpler:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :static_pages, only: :show, path: "", as: :country #-> domain.com/:id
```

This is the "conventional" way that Rails will provide a path for you. Whilst admittedly, it won't give you the `[country]_path` helper, it *will* keep your code super clean (as demonstrated below)

---

**Controller**

Your problem is with your *controller*, which you need to resolve before your routes will fix.

The *real* issue is that you're using 20 different controller actions. Is that *object orientated*? Nope.

I'd do this:

```
#app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
Class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
   def show
       country = params[:id]
       ... business logic
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to use the `country` variable as much as you need in the single `show` action. This *is* object orientated, as the `show` action will *show* your `static_page`

---

**Slug**

To give you the ["sluggable" URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL) ability, you'll be best using the [`friendly_id` gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id):

```
#app/models/your_model.rb
Class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   friendly_id :column, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

This gives you the ability to use the `country` object as a `slug` and not an `id`:

```
#view
<%= link_to "France", country_path("france") %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! but I don't think I can use params. I understood I failed to give enough context/explanations so I edited my question => see EDIT